# Returning null if multiple instances are found

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have an IEnumerable and a predicate (Func) and I am writing a method that shall return a value if only one instance in the list matches the predicate. If the criteria is matched by none, then none was found. If the criteria is matched by many instances, then the predicate was insufficient to successfully identify the desired record. Both cases should return null.

What is the recommended way to express this in LINQ that does not result in multiple enumerations of the list?

The LINQ operator SingleOrDefault will throw an exception if multiple instances are found.
The LINQ operator FirstOrDefault will return the first even when multiple was found.

```
MyList.Where(predicate).Skip(1).Any()
```

...will check for ambiguity, but will not retain the desired record.

It seems that my best move is to grab the Enumerator from MyList.Where(predicate) and retain the first instance if accessing the next item fails, but it seems slightly verbose.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: That really seems like two separate checks.  Perform the query, then check the Count.

Comment: The code in your question actually helped me find out _if there were_ multiple matches! +1!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "slightly verbose" option seems reasonable to me, and can easily be isolated into a single extension method:

```
// TODO: Come up with a better name :)
public static T SingleOrDefaultOnMultiple<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    // TODO: Validate source is non-null
    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            return default(T);
        }
        T first = iterator.Current;
        return iterator.MoveNext() ? default(T) : first;
    }
}
```

Comment: Only thing I would change is method name, if its possible to keep it in one line )

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy: And your suggestion for the name would be...? ;)

Comment: `LikeSingleOrDefaultButReturnNullInsteadOfThrowingIfThereAreMoreThanOne`

Comment: @Rawling: Well, "Null" doesn't necessarily describe it. So `LikeSingleOrDefaultButReturnDefaultOfTInsteadOfThrowingIfThereAreMoreThanOne` perhaps? ;)

Comment: @Rawling ha-ha :) I like this name - very descriptive

Comment: @Jon I thought I'd try to save six characters but I can see how it would be confusing :p (maybe you could still drop the `OfT` though...)

Comment: How about calling it "SingleOrDefault" and then have MS change the original to SingleOrDefaultOrException" ;)

Comment: I had to create similiar method. I named it as SafeSingleOrDefault.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: Here is a more general approach which might be more reusable.

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> TakeIfCountBetween<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int minCount, int maxCount, int? maxTake = null)
{
    if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    if (minCount <= 0 || minCount > maxCount)
        throw new ArgumentException("minCount must be greater 0 and less than or equal maxCount", "minCount");
    if (maxCount <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("maxCount must be greater 0", "maxCount");
    int take = maxTake ?? maxCount;
    if (take > maxCount)
        throw new ArgumentException("maxTake must be lower or equal maxCount", "maxTake");
    if (take < minCount)
        throw new ArgumentException("maxTake must be greater or equal minCount", "maxTake");

    int count = 0;
    ICollection objCol;
    ICollection<TSource> genCol = source as ICollection<TSource>;
    if (genCol != null)
    {
        count = genCol.Count;
    }
    else if ((objCol = source as ICollection) != null)
    {
        count = objCol.Count;
    }
    else
    {
        using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (enumerator.MoveNext() && ++count < maxCount);
        }
    }

    bool valid = count >= minCount && count <= maxCount;
    if (valid)
        return source.Take(take);
    else
        return Enumerable.Empty<TSource>();
}
```

Usage:

```
var list = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C", "E", "E", "F" };
IEnumerable<string> result = list
    .Where(s => s == "A")
    .TakeIfCountBetween(1, 1);
Console.Write(string.Join(",", result)); // or result.First()
```

Comment: But the OP wants the actual value - this doesn't give that, and using this *and* anything else will potentially require multiple evaluation (something to be avoided).

Comment: @JonSkeet: note that i've edited the method. But apart from that even the old approach stored the result in a variable.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. My point is that the OP wants a value of type `T`, not just a `bool`. So any method with a return type of `bool` isn't going to give them what they want, as I understand it. Your "usage" doesn't have any variable which is "the first value".

Comment: @JonSkeet: have a look at my variable named `result`. This contains what OP wants, in my example an `IEnumerable<string>`. I've edited it again to make it clearer (hopefully).

Comment: I don't think that *is* what the OP wants. I believe the OP wants a variable of type `string` - hence the references to `FirstOrDefault` and `SingleOfDefault` doing *nearly* what's required, but not quite. See my answer for my interpretation of the requirements.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Now i got the point! Since he wants only one it's clear that he wants to use `First`, edited it again accordingly. The reason for this misunderstanding was that my method could be used also more than one.

Comment: Right. And now my objection is that it's evaluating the sequence twice... which *could* end up being very expensive, depending on the sequence. Glad we're on the same page in terms of requirements though :)

Comment: Jon has it. The accepted answer from Jon nails my problem in a LINQ'ish way. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: @Tormod: if you're looking at a more general approach sometime (f.e. you want the first two if at least one but less than 3) have a look at my first approach.

Comment: I agree with that here I may be looking at special case of a more general method "ExactCount" or something. However, in this case I am looking to return an instance of T, not an IEnumerable<T>. Even though Where() arguably is a general case of First(), I appreciate both.